# Why Are My Mirrored Databases Changing States on Their Own?

Tags: sql-server-2005, mirroring

Setup:

- SQL Server 2005 w/SP4 64-bit Standard for all three servers
- Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise w/SP1 64-bit for all three servers
- 01 is designated as the Principal
- 02 is designated as the Mirror
- 03 is designated as the Witness

My issue is that there are Principal and Mirrored DBs on both servers and it is causing Maintenance Plans and SQL scripts to fail.

My questions:

1. Why are the DBs failing from one to the other when 01 should have all Principal DBs?
2. How do I stop this behavior
3. What is the least invasive process of changing the Principal DBs on 02 back to 01?

Comment: What mode is configured for each database mirror?

Comment: @Shawn, new to the mirroring configuration and I'm trying to learn more about it.  This was one of those things that got handed to me.  I started reading the whitepaper on MS's site about DB mirroring in 2005, but I've not gotten that far yet.  How to check for what you're asking?

Comment: Through SSMS, right-click a database then "task" and "Mirroring...". The properties window will open up and a grayed out portion "Operating Mode" should have a radio button beside one of three options: High Performance, High Safety W/ Failover, or High Safety W/out Failover. I would expect you should see High Safety with failover.

Comment: As well, under the same menu (Tasks) you can open the "Launch Database Mirroring Monitor" and view what is going on with the mirroring sessions.

Comment: @Shawn, thank you for the direction.  All DBs are set to "High safety with automatic failover (synchronous)"

Comment: I guess my next question is:  How can I make sure that 01 always stays the principal?  I want the DBs to always be available, so if 01 "needs" to failover over to 02, then I obviously want that.  Is there a way to force 02 to make 01 the principal again after 01 can support the DB?  I'm not versed enough in TSQL to write code that will verify if DBs are online or in a restoring state.  Further, I don't know how to configure Hallengren's scripts to work and report to the DBA team that the jobs failed or succeeded.  I guess that is my next step in the learning process.

Comment: I'm looking for an easy method for setup with MPs until I can get Hallengren's code to work or I'm more versed in TSQL.  Appreciate the help, direction, and any pointers in advance.

Comment: Under the same window that you viewed what mode they were in is a button for failover. You would do this from the current principal if I recall. You will see connections dropped so do it off hours if in production.

Comment: Okay, sounds good, it appears this is a manual process then?  In my mind, I figured the DBs would swap back since one server was designated as the principal.

Comment: It can fail back if the current principal has an issue but not until that time or you do it manually.

Comment: I feel this question has been answered and addressed to my satisfaction with the help of Shawn AND Shanky, but I'm not able to give credit to both since one is a comment(s) and one is an answer :(  Thank you both for the assist, I appreciate your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you please look at SQL Server errorlog and see if you could find some relevant information on both Principal and mirror. Generally if SQL Server CPU utilization goes high above 50 % there can be failover. This is specifically caused by heavy load on SQL Server this is documented in Below Microsoft Web resource See '**recommendation for Configuring partner Server**' in link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366349%28v=sql.100%29.aspx

This can be avoided by Alter partner time out

> Alter database db_name set partner timeout 20

Edit: After User provided more details

> Database mirroring connection error 4 'An error occurred while receiving data: '64(The specified network name is no longer available.)'.

As per this message its clear that network connecting principal and mirror flipped I dont know for how much time but this caused the failover. What happens is Mirror server keeps sending pings to Principal whether it is alive or not and suppose Principal goes down and now mirror will send 10 pings to principal(By default) and if it does not gets any response it will initiate failover with help of Witness( its little more complex with witness ,it involves quorum)

If it was for moment you can increase partner timeout( not a good practice though) but you should **Immediately speak to network team** and ask them RCA for this glitch as this caused failover. My course of action would be to meet them personally ask them to run bunch of commands to check response time

Comment: the following are the only messages I found in the error logs:  Database mirroring connection error 4 'An error occurred while receiving data: '64(The specified network name is no longer available.)'.' for 'TCP://SERVERNAME:PORT_NUMBER'.**********

The mirrored database "DB_NAME" is changing roles from "PRINCIPAL" to "MIRROR" due to Role Syncronization.

Comment: There are two messages there, but I can't format them in a comment :/

Comment: I have updated my answer please check. Immediately take help of Netwrok team this is a network issue